# Unity 5.6.0f3 does not compile any c# script (System.RuntimeType not found)

Tags: c#, mono, unity-game-engine

I just downloaded the latest Unity Version 5.6.0f3 and can't get any script to compile.

Steps:

1) Open Unity and create a new project

2) Add a script component to any object in the hierarchy

3) Press play

=> Error:

> Runtime critical type System.RuntimeType not found
>
> All compiler errors have to be fixed before you can enter playmode!
>   UnityEditor.SceneView:ShowCompileErrorNotification()

Any idea what can cause this error? I have no other scripts or assemblies in the asset folder. It's just a complete new project with one default script.

Platform: Windows 10 x64 (latest updates installed)

Unity: 5.6.0f3 x64

IDE: VS 2017 (but I did not use it yet, because even the default script fails to compile)

**Edit:**

Unity 5.5.3 x64:

> - Assertion at ..\mono\metadata\domain.c:718, condition `mono_defaults.runtimetype_class != 0' not met

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Test: MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

Comment: Why not copy and post that default script here?

Comment: Give us more details, what platform you're working on? Is your OS 64bit? What IDE you're using?

Comment: Interesting. What happens if you use MonoDevelop? Can you try that and see if you still get the-same error. I just want to see if this is Unity or Visual Studio problem....

Comment: Is your script named `Test.cs` in project file structure?

Comment: Yes it is. I already tried scripts with other names, same errors occuring

Comment: Doesnt make a difference using MonoDevelop. In fact to cause this error I even don't need to open any IDE.

Comment: Edit-->external Tools-->Preferences... Change IDE to MonoDevelop

Comment: This does not change anything. As I said, I do not open the IDE. I just create a new script in the Unity Editor. I also tried it with an IDE but that doesnt cause a different behaviour

Comment: Tried Unity 5.5.3 x64 to see if that works. Getting also a playmode error with a new Default script: * Assertion at ..\mono\metadata\domain.c:718, condition `mono_defaults.runtimetype_class != 0' not met

Comment: Which platform have you selected as a build target?

Comment: PC, Mac & Linux Standalone x86_64